# Авторизация для админки сайта

Tags: .htaccess, авторизация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли для админки сайта использовать авторизацию средствами сервера (.htaccess), не будет ли с этим каких-либо проблем? Пользователь будет всего 1.

Comment: Можно, но я никогда такое не использую.

Comment: Почему? Не надежно?

Comment: Ну, Это глуповато.

- можно организовать и не одного пользователя
- можно им права прикрутить с помощью php и mysql.

Не интересно. Хотя бы в одной CMS видели чтобы авторизация была через htaccess? 
-неудобно добавлять пользователей, т.к тут нужны навыки работы с файлом и файлом паролей. Не думаю что рядовой пользователь начнет с этим разбираться, удалит сразу такую систему.

Куда проще ввести логин и пароль в красивую форму. НА которой, кстати, может быть ссылочка для восстановления пароля к админке !

Comment: Спасибо, просто совершенно нет времени писать модуль авторизации.

Comment: 1 запрос в БД и проверка 2х полей, модуль готов :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смело используйте такой вариант авторизации, проблем никаких не будет. 
Здесь можно сгененрировать логин и пароль для файла: [Htpasswd Generator – Create htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).